# multisite hook for Add Existing User

Tags: multisite

I have a custom post type created for new users when they are added to a multisite environment using the wpmu_new_user hook, but I noticed that it was only fired on new user creation and not when an existing user is added to a site. Is there a hook that gets fired when both new or existing users are added to a site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one called [`added_existing_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/added_existing_user/) that fires immediately after adding an existing user.

Digging a little deeper, I find the function [`add_user_to_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_to_blog/) is used by both [`add_new_user_to_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_new_user_to_blog/) and [`add_existing_user_to_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_existing_user_to_blog/), and has an action hook named [`add_user_to_blog`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_user_to_blog/). I'd look into using that last hook, if I wanted to ensure something happened when a user was added to a site, whether they were `_new_` or `_existing_`.